# Rails query returns array instead of ActiveRecord

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have this query

```
documents = Broker.find(12).clients.left_joins(:documents).select("clients.id, count(documents.expiration) FILTER (WHERE documents.expiration < '#{Date.today}') AS expired").group("1")
```

And it returns me a table like this:

| id | expired |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 6 | 2 |

And I want to add an `order` after the query. For example:

```
documents.order("expired")
```

But I got this error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `order' for []:array)
```

What can I do to get an ActiveRecord instead of an Array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of `.group` invocation at the end of the expression. Documentation [says](https://apidock.com/rails/v6.1.3.1/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/group):

> Returns an array with distinct records based on the group attribute

So, in order to get an activerecord relation you should eliminate usage of `.group`.